# Any way to get a file system path for a razor page?

Tags: filepath, razor-pages, system-paths

For a page 'TestModel' in 'Pages/TestPages/' get a string like:
/linux or project root/project-name/Pages/TestPages/

Edit: I'm not looking to get a path from inside a running page. Let's say from startup.cs

Edit 2: I'm looking something like this:
string GetPath(PageModel Page)
string path = GetPath(TestModel)
path: "/linux or project root/project-name/Pages/TestPages/"

Comment: Have you tried `Server.MapPath`?

Comment: Server.MapPath doesn't exist in .net core but other than that, i need a method that returns a path based on a class(razor page), not based on a relative path i'll supply.

Comment: The Razor Page file doesn't exist as such in a running application. So the file path is only relevant on the development machine. Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to achieve - i.e. why you want this information. What use do you intend to make of it?